# Get taxonomy term links in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

For some reason I cannot get this to work. Here is what I have in my custom node template which is named node--news-feed.tpl.php..

```
<?php print render($content['field_company']); ?>
```

This should render out the taxonomy terms in that field, right?

Comment: Hi, Dustin. There is no way we can know that without knowing ore about your set-up. Did you clear your cache after creating the template file? If you `print_r($content['field_company'])` (or `dpr()` if using Devel), what do you get?

Comment: Yeah I cleared the cache, the template is definitely loading, just no value is coming from that render(). I'll install Devel and see what it tells me.